# why does my form password validation not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

good day people. 
I am trying to create a password validation before form submission using javascript and jquery
When the submit button is clicked I want it to validate password.
If password is not set, it will alert that password has not been entered. otherwise display success message and submit form.

Here is my javascript:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jinji.jinjer.biz/assets/templates/hr/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="login-form" target="dummyframe" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in">


    <input name="company_code" type="hidden" value="5709" />

    <input name="email" type="hidden" value="5685" />

    <input class="jpassword" name="password" type="password" />
    <input value="LogIn" class="submit" /><br><br>

  </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $(".submit").on('click', function() {
          var password = document.getElementByClassName("jpassword");
          if (password.val = "") {
            alert("Please Enter password");
            else {
              alert("Success. Now you can login");
              document.getElementById("login-form").submit();
            }
          }

        });

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My code doesnt work. Am i missing something?
You help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `password.val=""` is an assignment, not a check. This should be `password.val==""`

Comment: @ElianEbbing ALso `val` is an incorrect property name. Elements have no such property

Comment: thank you for your reply . can you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: lot error script, please see `if else` curly bracket "`{ }`"

Comment: Just a suggestion: try not to mix jQuery and js like you have in your code. If you are using jQuery for DOM lookup, then stick to it for consistency.